# Inheritance-chain, sub-class is not overriding method

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

I'm writing a game with objects that I want to use different commands depending on the class it is. I have a super-class 'Item', a sub-class 'Tool extends Item' and 'Hammer extends Tool'. In the Item super-class(which is abstract) I have an abstract method 'doCommand' which I override in Tool. This works well and I now have a working 'doCommand' in Tool. But when I want to override this 'doCommand' in Hammer it just uses the Tool's 'doCommand'.

```
public abstract class Item {
    public abstract void doCommand(String com1, Item i, Player player);
}

public class Tool extends Item {
    public void doCommand(String com, Item i, Player player) {    
         System.out.println("Not overridden.");    
    }
}

public class Hammer extends Tool {
    public void doCommand(String com, Item i, Player player) {    
         System.out.println("Overridden.");    
    }
}
```

This is from the part of the class that calls the method. The code above is just simplified code of what's happening.

```
String parts[] = com.split(" ");
String com1 = parts[0];
String com2 = parts[1];
for (Item i : player.getItems()) {
    if (com2.toUpperCase().equals(i.getName().toUpperCase())) {
        i.doCommand(com1, i, player);
        break;
    }
}
```

I expect it to print "Overridden." but I get "Not overridden.".

Comment: How are you calling?

Comment: Can you please paste the code of your main class? or the code from which you are calling the function doCommand?

Comment: I updated it, not sure this is what you're looking for though.

Comment: You probably want to make your `Tool` class abstract, because that's most likely the problem. Somewhere you instanciate a `Tool` (possible as it's not abstract), loop over it and thus are actually calling `doCommand()` of `Tool`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you call doCommand function.

If you call doCommand() like this:

```
 Hammer hammer = new Hammer();
 hammer.doCommand("", hammer, new Player());
```

OR

```
Item item = new Hammer();
 item.doCommand("",  item ,new Player());
```

It will print "Overridden". As long as you initialise as New Hammer(). it will get overriden.

But below will print "not overriden"

```
 Item item = new Tool();
 item.doCommand("", item, new Player() );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This wasn't exactly the solution but it got me thinking and I found it. Cheers!

Comment: @Win Han I made edit to your answer, You passed `new Item()` for all 3 cases.

Comment: @dirtydazzel this is a place where its not only you but others who take reference from your questions and answers and comments.  Just do not mark an answer as accepted if it got you thinking. If you found an answer yourself , you can upvote an answer which did not answered your question but got you thinking in right direction. **Add the correct answer you found and mark it as accepted**. This will prevent others from getting misguided

Answer (score 0):

You should have gotten "Overriden.". One integrity check one should *always* do, is to add `@Override` to verify that no typo exists in the signature, and indeed something is overriden.

```
public abstract class Item {
    public abstract void doCommand(String com1, Item i, Player player);
}

public class Tool extends Item {
    @Override
    public void doCommand(String com, Item i, Player player) {    
         System.out.println("Not overridden.");    
    }
}

public class Hammer extends Tool {
    @Override
    public void doCommand(String com, Item i, Player player) {    
         System.out.println("Overridden.");    
    }
}

Item item = new Hammer();
item.doCommand("", null, null); // "Overriden."
```

The mose likely cause for your error is a mixup of doCommand parameter Item and Item in the list.

(By the way, *multiple class inheritance* is another concept, not to confuse here.)